# How to group or cache emissions in complex processing flow?

Tags: rx-java

I'm using RX java for most of the processing in my tool. Basically the idea of the tool I'm working on is:

- get the Payload (e.g. HTML file) from some source
- split it into fragments using some specific rule.
- Each fragment might require some extra data to be fetched via asynchronous http call (can be one or more such calls to be made)
- each fragment might use exactly same http calls (endpoints)
- then use the data returned from http endpoint to do something with the fragment
- then combine all processed fragments back to the payload - let's call it "Processed Payload"
  Basically, the flow that I described I already implemented and works fine, simple marble diagram shows basic idea.

[image: Processing flow]

Not sure if diagram will be readable, so the pseudo-code of the processing looks like this:

```
    Observable.just("SOME_PAYLOAD_AS_STRING")
        .flatMap(payload -> splitToFragmentObservables(payload))  //Getting observables of fragments
        .concatMapEager( //concat all processed fragments
              fragment -> getServiceCallsObservable(fragment) //get service calls for all fragments
                          .flatMap(this::doServiceCall)  // do service call
                          .reduce(new HashMap<>(), (all, result) -> { //reduce results into map
                                all.addAll(result);
                                return all;
                          })
                         .map(all -> newFragmentWithData(fragment, all)) //apply somehow the all service results to my fragment
        )
        .reduce(new StringBuilder(), StringBuilder::append) //reduce all fragments back to string
        .map(StringBuilder::toString);
```

Now, I'm thinking how to improve some of the processing, especially HTTP calls. As you might noticed on the diagram, each fragment can do exactly the same calls (A, B or C) which is unnecessary overhead.

I'm looking for a way how to avoid doing same service calls in each fragment. What's the best way of improving it ? Group same calls, do the call and then somehow use it when doing the final result ? Or do some caching instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips. Actually, while I was looking for using guava cache I found elegant solution that also uses `cache` operator.

Simply flatMap operator that is mapping to service result Observable

```
.flatMap(this::doServiceCall)
```

I changed to use guava cache get method with callback that's executed when no value available for the given key

```
.flatMap(service -> cache.get(service.getUrl(), () -> doServiceCall(service.getUrl()).cache()))
```

So I'm simply caching cached observable from the service call. The cache is being reinitialized on each new payload that's being processed - kind of cache living for request only.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to cache the results produced by the `Observable` and give the same result to all subscribers.

You have two choices:

1. Use `cache` operator. But then you would have to implement cache invalidation.
2. Use more sophisticated solutions with `replay` and `publish` operators. But [@JakeWharton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132047/jake-wharton) has already coped with such problem giving [the solution](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxReplayingShare) for you. [Here](https://medium.com/@p.tournaris/rxjava-rxreplayingshare-emit-only-once-b19acd61b469#.1ya36hnmz) is the explanation of this simple library.

Extra:
[Here](https://medium.com/@p.tournaris/rxjava-one-observable-multiple-subscribers-7bf497646675#.1bg1lt29q) is another solution to the problem of emitting the same value for the Observable.

Hope, I understood the problem and gave proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Charles Proxy (or similar) to see what calls are actually being made.

If you are using a good Http library with caching then your code may already be perfect. Don't prematurely optimise!

Depending on the caching rules that your endpoints have (and whether you can change them) you may be able to use cached results for successive calls to the same endpoint. If you have control over these endpoints, then set lenient caching headers.

Adding caching to `getServiceCallsObservable` would probably be a much messier solution. It would also need to be thread-safe as `getServiceCallsObservable` gets called from different worker threads. (Well it should at least, you may need to add some extra scheduling depending on the implementation and scheduling details of some of your methods)